# How do I get a the end position of substring in a multiline textwidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a text widget with text inside, it has the `'\n'` character. The text is separated by lines. I've tried to use the search method to find the start position of the substring in the text widget. Then I've got a position like (2, 10). After that, I've calculated the length (18) of the substring and found out the end position by adding the length to the start position and got something like this 2.28.
But when there is a `'\n'` symbol inside the substring, it will be a wrong position. For example, if the `'\n'` symbol is in the 2.15 position, the end of the substring in the widget should be 3.13.
Is there a way to find the end position in a multiline text widget? Can I use the search method for that? How can I do this?

Comment: There is `rstrip()` that removes the `\n`. You can use that to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you might want to count each row. This method will count each row individually and the total count less the `\n`.

The function below will check each line and count it. Printing the results for that line and then adding those results to the counter. Lastly when the loop is done it will print the total count. I have also added a print statement that will give the the index of the last character for each row in the textbox.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x100")
txt = tk.Text(root, height=4, width=30)
txt.pack()


def string_count():
    global txt
    counter = 0
    for ndex, line in enumerate(txt.get(1.0, "end-1c").splitlines()):
        counter += len(line)
        print("Count on Line {} is: {}".format(ndex + 1, len(line)))
        print("The index for the last character in this line is {}.{}".format(ndex + 1, len(line)))
    print("String count in text box is: {}".format(counter))

tk.Button(root, text="Get string count", command=string_count).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index want to find a new index that is N characters away, you can use the `index` method along with the extended syntax of the text widget (eg: "line.character + n chars")

Here's a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)

text.insert("end", "line one\nthis is line two\nand this is the third line")

index = "2.10"
new_index = text.index("{} + {} chars".format(index, 18))
assert(new_index=="3.11")
```